# Time complexity difference - O(log log n) vs O(log n)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, logarithm

I'm reviewing how to calculate the time complexity of functions, and am struggling to reason the below:

From what I understand, O( log log n ) is smaller than O( log n ), given that:

```
O (log n) | O [ log (log n) ]

= O (log 100) | O [ log (log 100) ]

= O (2) | O [ log (2) ]

= O (2) | O [ 0.3010 ]
```

However, I believe the below snippet could be computed as O( log log n ):

```
p = 0
for( i=1; i<n; i=i*2 ) { 
    p++ // log n 
} 

for( j=1; j<p; j=j*2 ) { 
    some_statement // log P
}
// P=log n, ∴ O( log log n )
```

However, if we simply isolate the first loop, we get O( log n ), therefore having a greater growth in runtime than with both for loops.

Is the original evaluation of O( log log n ) incorrect? Otherwise, can you explain how introducing an additional for loop reduces the runtime complexity?

Thanks

Comment: You’re confusing the time complexity with the computation of the value. The loops aren’t nested, so your original complexity isn’t right.

Comment: Your argument is that the second loop takes O(log log n) time (correct), but then you incorrectly extend that to saying that the entire code takes O(log log n) time.

Comment: @PaulHankin ah i see, we should instead 'sum' the runtime of both for loops then?

Comment: I find it helpful to say what I'm measuring when using complexity. For example, "the code performs O(log log n) loop iterations." At the moment your language is quite vague (sorry, if English isn't your first language), like "the snippet could be computed as O(log log n)" in which doesn't mean anything specifically although various interpretations can be guessed.

Comment: You have to figure out what you're measuring, and then it's clearer. If it's statements, then you have to count the statements in whatever loops they are in (so "sum" is correct).

Comment: First loop takes θ(logn) time, second loop takes θ(loglogn) time, the whole program takes θ(logn) time (because that is the greater of those two).

Comment: You are right, O(log N) is "slower" than O(log log N), and that is the global complexity of the algorithm. But you contradict yourself with "I believe the below snippet could be computed as O(log log N)"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just assume that the whole algorithms has a time complexity of log log n. Since your first loop has a complexity of log n, you are correct in saying that the second loop has a **computation time** of log(log n), the whole algorithm still has a time complexity of log(n) though. This is because essentially, only the highest time complexity is considered.

You should also notice that Big O doesn't care about constant multipliers. If you have an algorithm with a computation time of 2500 log(n), it can still be considered log(n) in terms of Big O notation. Therefore, summing up multiple for-loops won't change the way time complexity is calculated

Answer (score 0):

Take `N=1.15792...10^77`. The first loop will be executed `1024` times. The the second will be executed `10` times. You can conclude.

---

Note that for moderate values of `N`, the difference between `log N` and `log log N` is really unimportant !